# JasperReports - displaying tiff's stored in BLOB in db

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jpeg, tiff, image-conversion

I want to display some tiff's which a stored in BLOB's in an oracle database. I just tried to convert them from tiff to jpg or png using im4java, but that didn't work. Maybe there is a possibility to display .tiff and other img data types in Jasper without converting them?! Or if not, does anybody have a detailed solution how to convert them? (which image class do I need to configure, how to implement in a scriptlet etc.)

Thanks everybody!

```
      IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
      op.addImage();
      op.addImage(); 

      ConvertCmd convert = new ConvertCmd();
      convert.run(op, new Object[]{inputImage.getAbsolutePath(), outputImage.getAbsolutePath()});
    return outputImage;`
```

Comment: In what way did it not work? Did the conversion fail? Are you unable to display the converted files? Did you get any exceptions or error messages?

Comment: @haraldK `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The cell cannot be added. at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.actions.export.AExportA‌​ction$3.run(AExportA‌​ction.java:188) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.` That's a part of the error message, so I think the conversion failed. I don't know how to exactly implement the code in a scriptlet, so the conversion executes before every detail band.. Another problem is that not all of the images are tiff, but also jpg and some more old img types..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, here's the code worked for me using jai-imageIO.jar to convert tiff to jpg:

> import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
> import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
> import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.InputStream;
>
> import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
> import javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry;
>
> import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractScriptlet;
> import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRScriptletException;

```
public static InputStream convertTifToPng(InputStream inputImage)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
    registry.registerServiceProvider(new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi());
    registry.registerServiceProvider(new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi());
    
    BufferedImage image;

    if (inputImage != null) {
        image = ImageIO.read(inputImage);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
    InputStream outputImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    return outputImage;
}
```